# 3-Ring Binder Equivalent

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a program that is the functional equivalent of a 3 ring binder (2 ring outside of North America). It would let me import photographs on separate pages, separate (full-page) pdf's, documents, etc. One use would be as a scrapbook, but another would be to keep a collection of different user manuals for equipment.

Scrivener comes close to what I'm looking for, but Scrivener treats pdf's as image files and only brings in the first page. In most cases the user manuals are multi-paged.

Assembling the pdf's as a single large pdf file doesn't work either, because the file quickly becomes enormous and users with (only!) 8gb of RAM find navigation difficult.

Is there anything else out there?

Comment: I think Microsoft [OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/signin?wdorigin=ondc) does this. As for handling multiple pages and packaging them into a PDF - check out [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/)